# Vsftpd crashes if I add anon_root directive

Tags: linux, gentoo, ftp

Here is a full config :

```
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES

connect_from_port_20=YES
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=myuser
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd_uploads.log

xferlog_std_format=YES
idle_session_timeout=600
data_connection_timeout=120
ftpd_banner=Welcome to my FTP server.

no_anon_password=YES

anon_world_readable_only=YES

anon_umask=077
anon_root = /var/ftp
chroot_local_user=YES
listen=YES
listen_port=20021
max_clients=30
max_per_ip=2
```

Everything works if I remove anon_root directive.

```
ls -lah /var/
drwxr-xr-x  2 ftp   ftp   4.0K Apr 11 21:01 ftp
```

Any glues ? It writes nothing to logs, no complains at all, just [ !! ] after restart. 
Tried to change almost everything, but don't see my mistake :(

Answer (score 1):

> Using vsftpd, you can't write command
>   with space, so anon_root =/var/ftp is
>   wrong , while anon_root=/var/ftp is OK
>   :( Horrible stuff!